RustDesk & Flutter web build errors | .dart files causing errors when attempting a web build
I'm having a lot of issues with the "flutter build web --release" command. This is for making a web build so that I may utilize the RustDesk web client services. I've been having a lot of issues with .dart files not being properly read in JS format. Here are the following errors when attempting to start the web build:
ptech@rustdeskdev:~/FOO/rustdesk/flutter$ flutter build web --release

Warning: In index.html:97: Local variable for "serviceWorkerVersion" is deprecated. Use "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}" template token instead. See
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization for more details.
Target dart2js failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 1:
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-3.4.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25:
Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verify'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verify(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^
lib/pages/scan_page.dart:54:58:
Error: Member not found: 'abgr'.
                            .getBytes(format: img.Format.abgr)
                                                         ^^^^
lib/pages/scan_page.dart:48:41:
Error: The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
                        File(file.path).readAsBytesSync(), file.path)!;
                                        ^
lib/pages/scan_page.dart:48:65:
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
                        File(file.path).readAsBytesSync(), file.path)!;
                                                                ^
lib/pages/scan_page.dart:54:39:
Error: No named parameter with the name 'format'.
                            .getBytes(format: img.Format.abgr)
                                      ^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dash_chat-1.1.16/lib/src/message_listview.dart:247:72:
Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
                                                                      .text));
                                                                       ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dash_chat-1.1.16/lib/src/widgets/message_container.dart:107:43:
Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../../rustdesk/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
                      ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dash_chat-1.1.16/lib/src/widgets/quick_reply.dart:43:60:
Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../../rustdesk/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
                      width: 1.0, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dash_chat-1.1.16/lib/src/widgets/quick_reply.dart:51:46:
Error: The getter 'accentColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../../../rustdesk/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
  Command: /home/ptech/rustdesk/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart /home/ptech/rustdesk/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/dart2js.dart.snapshot
  --platform-binaries=/home/ptech/rustdesk/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel --invoker=flutter_tool -Ddart.vm.product=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=false -DFLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true
  -DFLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=https://www.gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/9c3f66d822e499ee2109dd08b099554bdf2bc93f/ --native-null-assertions --no-source-maps -o
  /home/ptech/FOO/rustdesk/flutter/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5fe9e7ee08d54441cabe9828f988da50/app.dill --packages=/home/ptech/FOO/rustdesk/flutter/.dart_tool/package_config.json --cfe-only
  /home/ptech/FOO/rustdesk/flutter/.dart_tool/flutter_build/5fe9e7ee08d54441cabe9828f988da50/main.dart
#0      RunResult.throwException (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:122:5)
#1      _DefaultProcessUtils.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:389:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Dart2JSTarget.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/web.dart:202:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:891:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:520:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:829:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:520:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:829:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:651:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      WebBuilder.buildWeb (package:flutter_tools/src/web/compile.dart:92:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     BuildWebCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_web.dart:230:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1450:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:421:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:364:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:130:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                             13.5s
Error: Failed to compile application for the Web.

For added context, I am attempting to follow along with these following steps on how to get this build working correctly:
git clone https://github.com/JelleBuning/rustdesk.git
cd rustdesk
git switch fix_build
cd flutter/web/js

# Install protoc first, see: https://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html
npm install ts-proto
# Only works with vite <= 2.8, see: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/docs/guide/build.md#chunking-strategy
npm install vite@2.8

# Required for yarn build
npm install yarn -g
npm install typescript -g
npm install protoc -g

yarn build

cd ..

# About details of YUV converter, check this https://github.com/rustdesk/rustdesk/issues/364#issuecomment-1023562050
wget https://github.com/rustdesk/doc.rustdesk.com/releases/download/console/web_deps.tar.gz
# Decompress to the current directory
tar xzf web_deps.tar.gz

cd ..

flutter build web --release
cd build/web
# You could use any server, just an example
python -m http.server 8000

I am currently on the "flutter build web --release" step where I begin to run into my issues with getting this completed.
I have dart2js which is supposed to be helping compile the JS within the .dart files to be in a readable state, though when I compile the .dart files, I get an incredibly long list of errors for each and every .dart file present on the dev server even when specifying it to only compile one file in a given directory. Example:
ptech@rustdeskdev:~/FOO/rustdesk/flutter$ dart compile js ~/FOO/rustdesk/flutter/lib/pages/scan_page.dart
I just need a little bit of assistance with understanding what it is I'm doing wrong when it comes to these .dart files and why they seem to keep failing.

I have resolved this issue over the course of the weekend after posting the question. If others happen to stumble upon this post, what needs to be done is tracking down every single one of the .dart files that are listing the errors and work on replacing line by line all of the deprecated code. I was unfamiliar with .dart files so I wasn't sure initially where to begin, though after some further research I was able to discover what my solutions needed to be.
Additionally, there was an update for Flutter which cleared some of the .dart errors I was receiving as well such as the error listed for the ".abgr" file extension, after applying the newest update for Flutter, that error went away on its own.
In firebase_app.dart: Line 68
 int get hashCode => hashValues(name, options); 

was changed to
 int get hashCode => Object.hash(name, options);

In message_listview.dart: Line 247
 .text));

was changed to
 .text ?? ''));

In message_container.dart: Line 107
 ? Theme.of(context).accentColor

was changed to
 ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary

In quick_reply.dart: Line 51
 color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,

was changed to
 color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,

In toggle_switch.dart: Lines 165 & 175
Line 165
 ? Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.bodyText1!.color

was changed to
 ? Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.bodyLarge?.color

Line 175
 ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.color

was changed to
 ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.color

In html.dart: Line 30
 return Future<Uint8List>.value(UnmodifiableUint8ListView(_initBytes!));

was changed to
 return Future<Uint8List>.value(Uint8List.fromList(_initBytes!));

In bzip2.dart: Lines 5, 7, 9
Line 5
 UnmodifiableUint8ListView(Uint8List(0));

was changed to
 (Uint8List(0));

Line 7
 UnmodifiableUint32ListView(Uint32List(0));

was changed to
 (Uint32List(0));

Line 9
 UnmodifiableInt32ListView(Int32List(0));

was changed to
 (Int32List(0));

After making these changed manually to update the deprecated code, my web build was able to complete without any further errors. I hope this helps anybody who also gets stuck on this aspect of the web build.
